# Value in column containing comma delimited values

Tags: sql

My sql query results something like this:

```
ID     Col1      Col2
1      xsy       4,5,6
2      abc       4
3      hello     5,4
```

I want to filter results in which search string is also passed comma separator & should match col2 in all scenarios.

Like search string is 4, should return row 1,2 & 3. if search string is 5, should return row 1 & 3.

if I pass multiple search criteria with comma like 4,5 it should return row 1, 2 & 3 because all these rows has either one of matching number

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I am of the opinion that specially formatted strings are almost never a good thing in a db. Dbs are built to handle this sort of thing by putting col2 in a one to many table. I think that would make what you are trying to do easier. To be clear, you want to match rows that have all the same numbers as your input string? Does order matter?

Comment: **Don't do this!** This is a **horribly bad design** and violates even the **first normal form** of database design. This will cause you all sorts of grief down the road. Use **proper relational design** to handle multiple values - a second table linked with a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Listen to ajon and marc_s. As you may have noticed, this is a very bad way to store data. It will only cause you lots if trouble!

Comment: would you also have something like 55, 54, 56, 65, 53, 85 in your data? so that a simple like-query as shown in the answer of ytg would be incorrect?

Comment: Guys, it is existing system & I have to incorporate some change without modifying existing design. Yes, i've already tried query like ytg suggested, it won't work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Add commas before and after column value (to take care of first and last item),  then search for "comma value comma":

```
select * from tablename where ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,4,%'
```

|| is ANSI SQL for concat.

But you should really re-design your db and store values in a proper way!!!

Output when executed:

```
SQL>create table tso (id int, col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10));
SQL>insert into tso values (1,'xsy','4,5,6');
SQL>insert into tso values (2,'abc','4');
SQL>insert into tso values (3,'hello','5,4');
SQL>select * from tso where ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,4,%';
         id col1       col2
=========== ========== ==========
          1 xsy        4,5,6
          2 abc        4
          3 hello      5,4

                  3 rows found

SQL>insert into tso values (4,'extra','5,14');
SQL>insert into tso values (5,'extra','54,41');
SQL>select * from tso where ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,4,%';
         id col1       col2
=========== ========== ==========
          1 xsy        4,5,6
          2 abc        4
          3 hello      5,4

                  3 rows found
```

Another example:

```
SQL>select * from tso where ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,4,%'
SQL&                    and ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,5,%';
         id col1       col2
=========== ========== ==========
          1 xsy        4,5,6
          3 hello      5,4

                  2 rows found

SQL>select * from tso where ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,4,%'
SQL&                     or ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,5,%';
         id col1       col2
=========== ========== ==========
          1 xsy        4,5,6
          2 abc        4
          3 hello      5,4
          4 extra      5,14

                  4 rows found
```

Comment: I have also tried this solution. It results only row#2; not row#1 & 3 which has 4 value along with other values

Comment: Try   something like this:select * from tso where ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,4,5,%'; You should get row id#1,2 & 3. if you're not getting, it is issue.

Comment: If you want both value 4 and value 5, you'll need to AND two LIKE's, one for each value. If you want either value, use OR instead!

Answer (score 0):

That data model is horrible and will cause you a lot of pain in the future. If possible, you should introduce a detail table for the col2 values.

However, if you absolutely cannot change your data model, here's one way to do it:

- split col2 into separate values (e.g. using regular expressions, if your RDBMS supports it)
- use an `IN` list to filter out only the values you want
- use a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to get only the rows that have all the values you want

Using Oracle syntax:

```
with v_data(id, col1, col2) as (
  select 1, 'xsy',   '4,5,6'  from dual union all
  select 2, 'abc',   '4'      from dual union all
  select 3, 'hello', '5,4'    from dual union all
  select 4, 'hi',    '45,511' from dual
),
v_data_with_numbers as (
  select id, col1, col2, 
    regexp_substr(col2, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) as val
  from v_data
  connect by level <= 3
),
v_distinct_data_with_numbers as (
  select distinct id, col1, col2, val
  from v_data_with_numbers
  where val is not null
  order by id, col1, col2, val
)
select id, col1, col2
from v_distinct_data_with_numbers
where val in (4,5)
group by id, col1, col2
having count(distinct val) = 2 -- require both 4 and 5 to be present; omitting this line will give you all rows that have either one present
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try again like this

```
select * 
from TABLENAME f
where 'searchvalue' = ANY (string_to_array(COLUMNNAME,','))
```

Example

```
select * 
from customer f
where '11' = ANY (string_to_array(customerids,','))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Select * from table_name where col2 like "4"
```

Comment: That's not even valid SQL. I think you mean '%4%'

Comment: yes I meant something like Select * from table_name where col2 like '%4'